# What are your favorite BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) sniffing tools? (Hardware and Software)

Tags: sniffer, bluetooth, sniffing, debugging

I will soon need to debug BLE communication for a newly developed BLE device.

What are your favorite BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) sniffing tools? (Hardware and Software)

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, product recommendation questions are off-topic. We are a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. So, the idea here is that there can be a single acceptable answer to a question. A call for lists doesn't suit the format.

Comment: ok,understood. (even if i saw many "open" questions)